# How to extend custom taxonomy dropdown filter in Wordpress admin so that it shows all existing terms

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type - "FAQ" with taxonomy - "FAQ Category". In the list of FAQ in admin, there is a default dropdown filter for "FAQ Category". That's all good, but the dropdown does not show the terms which has no posts or has draft posts. How can I extend/modify this so that it shows all existing terms?

Comment: So you want the filter drop down to also include taxonomies that have posts in 'draft'?

Comment: @TonyDjukic Yes.